# Unit testing - how to split cases into multiple files that all share the same setUp/tearDown?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have one test suite in a single file that is getting very long. It doesn't make sense to split the test cases into different classes because they all test different steps of the same user flow. This is also why they share the same `setUp`/`tearDown` methods and share class variables. Certain tests also depend on other tests - e.g. test 1 progresses to some part of the user flow and executes some assert statements, then test 2 continues from that stage of the user flow to execute more assert statements.

Comment: You can split the classes into multiple subclasses that inherit `setUp` and `tearDown` from a common base class, and those subclasses can be spread across multiple modules. Tests should be independent of each other. If test 1 does something that test 2 relies on, you need to create a new test fixture for test 2.